# Insert template value in url string

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router, auth0

In the router below `:workflowId` is recognized as dynamic value.

My url looks like `localhost:4200/#/workflow/391`

```
{
        path: 'workflow/:workflowId',
        loadChildren: '*some module*',
        pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

How to do the same in the `redirect_uri` below?

Currently, `:workflowId` is recognized as a string and my url looks like `localhost:4200/#/workflow/:workflowId`

```
login(redirectPath: string = '/') {
        this.auth0Client$.subscribe((client: Auth0Client) => {
            client.loginWithRedirect({
                redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/#/workflow/:workflowId`,
                appState: { target: redirectPath }
            });
        });
}
```

**UPDATE**

`workflowId` is not my variable. See the `routing.ts` file below.

```
export const MAIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainPageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'workflow',
                loadChildren: '../flow-panel/flow-panel.module#FlowPanelModule',
                data: { isShowMenu: false },
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'workflow/:workflowId', // Here :workflowId is recognized as any id (number)
                loadChildren: '../task-management/task-management.module#TaskManagementModule',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            ...
```

Comment: workflowId must be a propery/variable. So you will be able to replace `:workflowId` with `${workflowId}`

Comment: ```workflowId``` is not my variable

Comment: It must be a variable. How did you get your workflowId then ?

Comment: Please, see the update